# how to reslove You don't have permission to access /< on this server...error

Tags: php

I am a php beginner. My question is whenever I am trying to validate my form using php and when I run it on localhost which is a wamp server it gives me a error message which is:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /< on this server.

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Please post the PHP and HTML surrounding your `<form>` element's opening tag. I suspect you aren't enclosing your `action=""` attribute correctly.

Comment: Which OS(Operating System Windows7-8, Linux) are you using?

Comment: and did you tried accessing `http://localhost` what is its output?

Comment: I think it is the Apache config syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some code like this:

```
if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this file directly');
```

If not then some database connection problem have there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\ ,right click on "wamp" folder,click the "security" tab ,click on "edit".In the "Group or user names" textbox/section,pick "your login name" and check "Full control".Click ok when you through.
Go to C:\wamp,right click on "www" and do the same as above.

OR

Type in "127.0.0.1" without the quote in your browser

Remember to "Mark/Tick" if this solve your problem.